# Run Facebook Flow on a Continuos Integration Meteor application

Tags: meteor, continuous-integration, sh, flowtype

I have a Meteor application with Circle CI as continuous integration service.

Facebook Flow is running locally with the following `.flowconfig`:

```
[ignore]
.*/node_modules/.*

[options]
module.name_mapper='^\/\(.*\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/\1'
module.name_mapper='^meteor\/\(.*\):\(.*\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/\1_\2'
module.name_mapper='^meteor\/\(.*\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/\1'
```

In CI I get errors like:

```
client/main.jsx:4
  4: import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ meteor/meteor. Required module not found
```

Flow seems not to find my modules. The rewrite rules do not apply. With SSH access to Circle CI I found ot that the `<PROJECT_ROOT>/.meteor/local` directory is not present.

Once I run `meteor` on the CI machine the directory will appear.

Problem: If I run `meteor` the Meteor server will start up and my test will time out.

As far as I see I need to either

1. Adapt my `.flowconfig` or
2. Find a way to get Meteor to create the directory without running `meteor` or
3. Find a way to kill the `meteor` process once the server is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with the third option:

[bbaja42](https://superuser.com/users/8238/bbaja42) shared a [script](https://superuser.com/a/373021/48042) that saves the output of a program and terminates the program once a keyword is reached.

Adapted to my case I have two files:

### `ci-tests.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

# Check if the output directory exits. Flow needs the modules there.
if [ ! -d ".meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages" ]; then
  echo "Meteor build directory does not exist. Starting Meteor."
  # Run Meteor so the output directory is built.
  ./build-and-kill-meteor.sh
else
  echo "Meteor build directory exists"
fi

./node_modules/.bin/flow --json
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
   exit 1
fi
```

### `build-and-kill-meteor.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

OUTPUT=/tmp/meteor-launch.log
PROGRAM=meteor
$PROGRAM > $OUTPUT  &
PID=$!
echo Program is running under pid: $PID

#Every 10 seconds, check requirements
while true; do
   tail -1 $OUTPUT
   grep "App running at: http://localhost" $OUTPUT
   if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
      break
   fi
   sleep 10
done

kill $PID || echo "Killing process with pid $PID failed, try manual kill with -9 argument"
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and came up with my own derivation based on the OP's answer. I run this script on **every** CI build to ensure that Meteor will always install any new atmosphere packages that I'm shipping with.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Install meteor
if [ -d ~/.meteor ]; then sudo ln -s ~/.meteor/meteor /usr/local/bin/meteor; fi
if [ ! -e $HOME/.meteor/meteor ]; then curl https://install.meteor.com | sh; fi

OUTPUT=/tmp/meteor-launch.log
PROGRAM=meteor
$PROGRAM > $OUTPUT  &
PID=$!
echo Program is running under pid: $PID

# Start meteor to install atmosphere packages
while true; do
   tail -1 $OUTPUT
   grep "Your application is crashing." $OUTPUT
   # Cancel the program once meteor has started
   if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
      break
   fi
   sleep 10
done

kill $PID || echo "Killing process with pid $PID failed, try manual kill with -9 argument."
```